# How to install NumPy for Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pip

I am using Python 3.6b3 for a long running project, developing on Windows.
For this project I also need NumPy.
I've tried Python36 -m pip install numpy, but it seems that pip is not yet in the beta.
What's the best way to install NumPy for Python 3.6b3?

[EDIT: Added installation log, after using ensurepip]

```
D:\aaa\numpy-1.12.0b1>call C:\Python36\python.exe -m pip install numpy 
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.11.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy: started
    Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command C:\Python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\info_000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-ueljt0po\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-nmezr3c7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Running from numpy source directory.

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install numpy`   (last Numpy release on PyPi)


    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1630: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1639: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1642: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Python36\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python36\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Python36\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python36\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Python36\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python36\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Python36\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python36\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python36\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python36\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Python36\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python36\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python36\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python36\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Python36\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Python36\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1532: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Python36\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1543: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1546: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.6\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.6\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Inumpy\core\src\private -Inumpy\core\src -Inumpy\core -Inumpy\core\src\npymath -Inumpy\core\src\multiarray -Inumpy\core\src\umath -Inumpy\core\src\npysort -IC:\Python36\include -IC:\Python36\include /Tc_configtest.c /Fo_configtest.obj
    Could not locate executable cl.exe
    Executable cl.exe does not exist

    failure.
    removing: _configtest.c _configtest.obj
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\setup.py", line 386, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\setup.py", line 378, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 169, in setup
        return old_setup(**new_attr)
      File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 62, in run
        r = self.setuptools_run()
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\install.py", line 36, in setuptools_run
        return distutils_install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build.py", line 47, in run
        old_build.run(self)
      File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 147, in run
        self.build_sources()
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 158, in build_sources
        self.build_library_sources(*libname_info)
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 293, in build_library_sources
        sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
      File "C:\Users\info_000\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-ueljt0po\numpy\numpy\distutils\command\build_src.py", line 376, in generate_sources
        source = func(extension, build_dir)
      File "numpy\core\setup.py", line 653, in get_mathlib_info
        raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
    RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program

    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Last time I saw a question like this, 3.6 was too new, too much in development.

Comment: @hpaulj You may be right. Just such a shame to miss fstrings, but probably I'll have to retreat to Python 3.5.

Answer (score 9):

As long as binary packages (so-called 'wheels') for 3.6 have not been released to PyPi yet, you can resort to unofficial (but working) ones available at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. Download the file and install it like this:

```
pip install C:\path\to\numpy‑1.11.3+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Answer (score 2):

Pip itself is not part of Python.  However, since version 3.4 Python includes the [`ensurepip` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html) that allows bootstrapping a pip installation.  After calling

```
python3.6 -m ensurepip
```

you should be able to install numpy via pip.

Comment: I could indeed intall pip that way.But when I use it, something goes wrong. I'll add the installation log to my question.

Comment: There is no precompiled numpy wheel available for Python 3.6, so numpy needs to be compiled on your machine.  Given how hostile Windows is as a platform for software development, it is likely rather tricky to get all your dependencies right, and I certainly can't help you with that.  I've left this special kind of hell behind in 1999 and never looked back. :)

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge My answer to that is "if you must use Windows, at least use Cygwin"

Answer (score 2):

Pip is always be installed in subdirectory `\Scripts` of the Python 3.6 install directory.

Open command prompt in windows, change directory to `\Scripts` and input `pip list`, you will see what has been installed, then input `pip install numpy`, and the numpy will be installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can install numpy through command prompt using pip install command. Follow the below steps:
1) In your command prompt, go to the scripts folder inside your Python 3.x installation.

2) Type following command on your command prompt

```
install numpy
```

Refer the attached screenshot showing both the steps.[image: Installation steps for numpy]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I misread the question, disregard this answer.

Try manually [downloading the wheel from pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/numpy) and installing manually.
On windows, it should look something like this:

```
C:/path/to/python36/pip.exe install C:/path/to/numpy_foo_.whl
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of steps needed to be performed for installing numpy on windows. This worked for me.

1. Set path variable for python- C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32
2. Download get-pip.py locally
3. Open cmd and navigate to get-pip.py file
4. run python get-pip.py for installation of PIP
5. set pip path in env variable path -  C:\Users\XXXXXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts;
6. pip install numpy