# Python can't import NUMPY

Tags: python, numpy

I have Python 3.6 installed on Windows 10 PC. I have installed Numpy but when I try to import it, Python can’t find it.
My IDLE shows:

> Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5, Jul  8 2017, 04:57:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

My command line Python can import Numpy.
It shows:

> Python 3.6.5 32 bit.

How do I get my IDLE to tun the version of Python that can Import Numpy?

Comment: try first answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40893602/how-to-install-numpy-for-python-3-6

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the information from running `sys.path` in IDLE and on the Command line?